# Spring security config, No child element is expected at this point.Invalid content was found

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to add the `security-config.xml` file and in `web.xml` by using `ContextLoaderListener`, but after trying to add the `<param-value>` for `security-config.xml` got the error says:

> Invalid content was found starting with element 'param-value'. No
>   child element is expected at this point.

The `jpaContext.xml` was used for JPA configuration, so I cannot remove it. What should I do at this point?

```
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml</param-value>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: do you have 'dataSource' in both jpaContext.xml and security-config.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContextLoaderListener` supports having multiple `contextConfigLocation`. Each context configuration file should be separated by spaces (new line or space). See an example below:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:/jpaContext.xml /WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The error you are experiencing is caused by having multiple `<param-value>` tags under `<context-param>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use comma :

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
      classpath:/jpaContext.xml, /WEB-INF/config/security-config.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>
```